# What does Language Model look like?

Tags: text-mining, model, natural-language

I am working on a machine learning + NLP project. The corpora is from **a very specific domain**. Someone tells me I need a language model for that specific domain. So I decide to build one myself since there's none yet.

My questions are:

1. **What does a language model look like?** Is it in the form of a bunch
   of n-gram words and probabilities?

   Maybe like this?

   term 1, probability 1

   term 2, probability 2

   term 3, probability 3

   term 4, probability 4

   ...
2. **How to obtain a language model?** Should I get a corpus of the domain and just summarize the term frequencies?
3. **How to use the language model?** Suppose I get a new document for the domain, and I want to vectorize the document, should I directly assign probabilities from the language model to the terms in the document? and generate. If so, the same terms from different documents will have identical probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, in essence a language model is a collection of n-grams together with their probabilities as observed in the data set (modulo smoothing)

2) There are many toolkits for language modelling, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel. See for instance the IRSLM and IRSTLM toolkits, which allow you to easily estimate N-gram models of arbitrary size from a file of training data.

3) Your last question is impossible to answer without having a clearer idea of what you are trying to do in your application.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding 3), I am trying to clustering a bunch of documents. I am considering to vectorize them first, and then use some vector similarity measure during the clustering.

Comment: Yes, in this case you can simply query the language model (LM toolkits generally provide specific methods for efficiently querying the model) to obtain the probabilities required to construct your document vectors.